# PhoneGap Backend Database - Google App Engine DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine, cordova, google-cloud-datastore, mobile-application

I have developed a PhoneGap application (HTML5,CSS,JS). The app needs to create product items using a form and then store that information in the gae DataStore. The app also needs to display all the products stored in DataStore.

I am new to both Web Development & Google App Engine. Can you please point me to an example (sample) code that uses PhoneGap & Google App Engine DataStore.

Comment: @proppy java - I am new to JavaScript (calling java function form HTML).

Answer (score 2):

If using java, you can implement your backend using a REST framework like [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/), [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [Cloud Endpoint](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/)

If using python, you can implement you backend using a REST framework like [Flask-Restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Cloud Endpoint](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/).

Alternatively you can consider using something like [gwt-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted) that provide direct integration of phonegap with [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/).

You can call it from Phonegap using your [preferred javascript library](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) or `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Can i use python? If yes, then can you please elaborate how to use that?

Comment: @Niks added some link for Python